# SQL/PHP Laravel - Looping through records to find relationships

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have two tables in my database, which contains a big list of organisations. They are called `orgs_main` and `orgs_sub`.  This is the structure:

**orgs_main**:

```
id | code | name | address |
----------------------------
```

**orgs_sub**:

```
id | code | name | address | merged |
-------------------------------------
```

`orgs_main` contains "main" organisations, which are identified by that they have a `code` starting with "64"

`orgs_sub` contains "sub" organisations, which are identified by they don't have a `code` starting with "64".

I need to find all the **sub** organisations, which have matching address to the **main organisations**, and then list them.

Example:

**Broadway Avenue 110** (`orgs_main`)

- Company 1 (`orgs_main`)
- Company 2 (`orgs_main`)
- Company 3 (`orgs_main`)
- Sub company 1 (`orgs_sub`)
- Sub company 2 (`orgs_sub`)

The way I am doing this now, is like this:

`MergerController.php`:

```
public function merger()
{
        //Select main organisations, that have matching addresses on sub-organisations and that is not already merged together.
        $MainOrganisations = DB::table("orgs_main AS j")
        ->selectRaw("DISTINCT j.address, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orgs_sub i WHERE i.address = j.address) AS SubCount")
        ->whereRaw("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orgs_sub i WHERE i.address = j.address AND i.merged=0) > 0")
        ->simplePaginate(10);

        //Loop through the main companies, so we get all main companies with the same address.
        foreach($MainOrganisations as $key => $SameAddress){
                $CompaniesSameAddress = DB::table('orgs_main')
                ->select('name', 'code')
                ->where('address', $SameAddress->address)
                ->where('code', 'LIKE', '64%')
                ->get();
                $SameAddress->Companies = $CompaniesSameAddress;
        }

        //Foreach found Main Organisation Address, list all the sub companies with this address.
        foreach($MainOrganisations as $key => $MainOrganisation){

            $SubOrganisations = DB::table('orgs_sub')
            ->select('name', 'code', 'id')
            ->where('address', $MainOrganisation->address)
            ->get(); 
            $MainOrganisation->SubOrganisations = $SubOrganisations;

        }
            //Return the data to our view.
            $data = [
              'MainOrganisations'            => $MainOrganisations,
            ];
            return $data;
}
```

My view file:

`merger.list.blade.php`:

```
<table width="100%" class="merger">
    @foreach ($MainOrganisations as $Main)
        <thead>
            <th>{{ $Main->address }}  </th>
            <th>
            @foreach($Main->Companies as $Companies)
                {{$Companies->name}} (Code: {{ $Companies->code }}) <br />
            @endforeach
            </th>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
         @foreach($Main->SubOrganisations as $Sub)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $Sub->name }}</td>       
                <td>{{ $Sub->code }}</td>
            </tr>

        @endforeach
        </tbody>

    @endforeach
</table>
```

Which shows something like this:

[image]

Any comments or alternatives methods is highly appreciated, as above code does function as intended, but it's quite slow and feel a bit "hackish" to me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you seen Eloquent documentation? Do you have relationships defined in the model(s)? What is `merged` field? How are you getting the company lists, do you have power to change schema? Can you *re-import* the data if needed?